# Angular Dart Router: navigating to the same component does not create a new instance even if canReuse() returns false

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-router

I'm using dart 2.0.0

With dart 1.24.3 and related angular router, I had a component with `CanReuse()` always returning `false`. In this case, when I navigated again to the same component, a new instance was created.
On the first call, `onActivate()` was called, and, when called the second time, the `CanReuse()` was executed and finally the `onActivate()` method on a new instance was called.

Now, with the last version, when we navigate a second time to the same component, `CanReuse()` and `onActivate()` are not called, and the same instance of the component is used.
Is there any way to change this behavior?

Edit 1:
Consider like you have a menu and each menu item navigate to a component. If you press the same menu item the same component is called. In my case the component called can manage data from different servers, so I can have multiple dataset active (but only one shown, almost like a tab..) at the same time. I have a list of open datasets, where the ones "not showed" are listed and you can select them again. There is a mechanism that preserve data and reinitialize the newly created instance from the selected one.
Theoretically I could manage everything in one instance only, but, as the logic is quite complicated, I would like to avoid it, and, in any case, I'd need to know when the menu item component (new or initialized from an existing dataset) has been selected (with an  `onActivate()` call, for example..).
At present this only works if I select different components, let's say, for example, component A, component B, and then again component A.
If I call component A and then again component A, the `onActivate()` method is not called and I'm not able to know when a different dataset is needed.

Comment: Are you navigating away before you navigate to the component again?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "navigating away"?

Comment: Navigating to a different route. If the route is the same I'm pretty sure Angular just does nothing. I think `CanReuse` is only if you change the route and but the component is the same.

Comment: With dart 1.24.3 it was working